# Run kubernetes cluster directly on ubuntu (vps)

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, vps, kubernetes

Currently I am experimenting with local hosted clusters using minikube. For a project I want to run a cluster of 1-2 nodes on my ubuntu VPS server. As I can not calculate the need of resources such as RAM I try to run it on a VPS server instead using AWS services.

As I am pretty new to all these topics I have no idea how to start at all. I'd guess I need a cluster management tool such as kops (which is used for AWS). My question is if its possible to run a kubernetes cluster directly on an ubuntu system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MicroK8s by ubuntu will let you create cluster on single machine. Please have a look at the following blog for step by step instructions:

https://itnext.io/a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s-33ee31d1eed9